# i only get the last record from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

it's a simple matter, but i don;t get it

i have two tables in a DB
date and newsmail
in date i have some columns ID, name, address, email, etc
in newsmail i have 2 fields ID, mail

i need to extract all records from date, that contains emails addresses from newsmail

i've tried :

```
SELECT * FROM date WHERE date.email IN (SELECT mail FROM newsmail);
```

i receive only one record from date with the last row from newsmail
also

```
SELECT * FROM date d JOIN newsmail n ON d.email LIKE n.mail
```

same result as above...
email and mail fields are `VARCHAR(50)`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad06/1/0
here it's working, but not on my real DB

the problem was at inserting data to newsmail from txt file

INITIAL :

```
$tmpfisier = $_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"];
$file_handle = fopen($tmpfisier, "r");
    while(!feof($file_handle)){
        $email_line = fgets($file_handle);
        $values = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  newsmail (`ID` ,`mail`) VALUES ( NULL ,  '$email_line')");
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
```

EDITED :

```
$tmpfisier = $_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"];
$file_handle = fopen($tmpfisier, "r");
    while(!feof($file_handle)){
        $raw_email_line = fgets($file_handle);
        $email_line = preg_replace('/\s\v/u', '', $raw_email_line);
        $values = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  newsmail (`ID` ,`mail`) VALUES ( NULL ,  '$email_line')");
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
```

so the problem was WHITESPACES from txt/csv file

THANK YOU ALL !!!

Comment: Try something like this: "SELECT * FROM date WHERE date.email IN (SELECT mail FROM newsmail)"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Date a
        INNER JOIN NewsMail b
            ON a.email LIKE CONCAT('%', b.mail, '%')
```

Comment: Shouldn't `_` and `%` be escaped in `b.mail`?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel yep, but i have no idea how the values looked like.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM date d
INNER JOIN newsmail n
    ON n.mail = d.email;
```

Comment: result : first column (n.mail) with emails from newsmail, rest of columns with NULL, and somewhere in the middle, i have one row with the fields coresponding with the last record from newsmail

Comment: Can you provide a sample on sqlfiddle.com? @GabrielPetrut

Comment: this is very strange. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad06/1/0 on sqlfiddle it's working

Answer (score 0):

The TRIM function may be needed to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
SELECT * FROM date d LEFT JOIN newsmail n ON TRIM(d.email) = TRIM(n.mail)
```

For SQLSERVER, you may need to use the LTRIM and RTRIM together to get the same results.

```
SELECT * FROM date d LEFT JOIN newsmail n ON RTRIM(LTRIM(d.email)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(n.mail))
```